# How to reload the configuration file as a systemd daemon (or service), upon receiving SIGHUP?

Tags: systemd, c++

I am trying to write a systemD daemon for my program. While I was reading the Linux man page, I noticed a line:

> If SIGHUP is received, reload the configuration files, if this applies.

My question is how can I "reload the configuration files" in C/C++, upon receiving SIGHUP?

I have seen others restart the daemon, by `execv(self, args);`, when receiving SIGHUP. However, is there a way that I can reload the configuration files, without restarting the daemon?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It really depends on your program and what it's supposed to do. In some cases you have to restart. For instance, if your configuration file includes a port the daemon listens to, there's no way to reload without restarting the service. So again, it really depends on your program, how it reads the configuration, applies it and keeps the setting in its memory. I assume your question is not on "how to create a signal handler" and that you already know how to do that.

Comment: Hi, aviro

Thanks a lot for your suggestions! I think you answered my question perfectly. I have another question if you don't mind answering: What is the correct (or conventional) way to read configuration file? Should I just treat it as a generic file and read it literally, or is there any built-in functions in C/C++ that I may use?

Comment: I don't know, this is more a programming question than Unix/Linux. I suggest you try at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from this and implement the pure virtuals:

```
class LinuxOSService
{
public:
    LinuxOSService()
    {
        sigemptyset(&sigset_);
        sigaddset(&sigset_, SIGINT);
        sigaddset(&sigset_, SIGTERM);
        sigaddset(&sigset_, SIGHUP);
        sigaddset(&sigset_, SIGUSR1);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset_, nullptr);
        wait_thread_ = std::thread(&LinuxOSService::signal_handler, this);
    }

    virtual ~LinuxOSService()
    {
        wait();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        if (wait_thread_.joinable())
            wait_thread_.join();
    }

    void abort()
    {
        abort_ = true;
        raise(SIGUSR1);
    }

    virtual void on_terminate() = 0;
    virtual void on_reload() = 0;

private:
    sigset_t sigset_;
    std::thread wait_thread_;
    std::atomic<bool> abort_ = false;

    void signal_handler()
    {
        int signum;
        siginfo_t siginfo;
        while (!abort_)
        {
            signum = sigwaitinfo(&sigset_, &siginfo);
            if(abort_)
                break;
            if (signum == -1)
            {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                    continue;
                break;
            }
            if (signum == SIGINT
                || signum == SIGTERM)
            {
                on_terminate();
                break;
            }
            else if (signum == SIGHUP)
                on_reload();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).